# how to call index object of json data

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

i have json data from server.

```
{"brand_id" : "14", "brand_name" : "Honda"}
```

I call theme through jquery `$.getJSON`

```
$.getJSON('data.php',function(json){
   $('select').append('<option value="'+ json.brand_id +'">' + json.brand_name + '</option>'
});
```

And it works well.
The problem is i want replace **brand_id** / **brand_name** be numeric index
like `json.brand_id` be `json[0]` / `json.brand_name` be `json[1]` . 
This can not work well.
How can i get theme?
please help !

Comment: Hmm...mind if I ask *why*? (JSON has no order, the index could change)

Comment: There is no problem. Objects don't use indices. You can put them in any order you wish and use the same code you have now.

Comment: @ tymeJV,
yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('data.php', function(json) {
    jsonCopy = {};
    var count = 0;
    $.each(json, function(i, v) {
        jsonCopy[count] = v;
        count++;
    });
    json = jsonCopy;
    $('select').append('<option value="' + json[0] + '">' + json[1] + '</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `json[0]` and `json[1]`, your server side data should change to

```
["14", "Honda"]
```

Or

```
{"0": "14", "1": "Honda"}
```

Comment: thanks xdazz.. which is a good alternative.
but I want to keep the file server